# Downloading & Parsing Multiple XML Files using WP7

Tags: c#, php, multithreading, windows-phone-7, webclient

I've run into a bit of a confusing issue, and I'm not sure if the problem is that I'm unaware of the WebClient "OpenReadCompletedEvent" delegate, or if there's a problem with my chosen solution used on my server side scripts, with which the app interacts with.

Here's my issue:

I have a class that defines a Video Game title, I use a WebClient to asynchronously open an RSS feed for reading, which, when completed continues to fetch user submitted information about that title using the same method. For this, I loop through each Video Game title parsed from the RSS feed (GameStop.com's RSS feed for upcoming games), here's where I'm running into problems, there's no way for me to keep all of these OpenReadCompletedEvent delegates synchronized, or none that I'm aware of.

Right now my code is becoming embarrassing and convoluted, and I believe it's incorrect:
Note: games is a List of Game objects.

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            for(int i = 0; i < games.Count; i++)
            {
                threads.Add(new Thread(downloadHype));
                threads[i].Start(i);
            }

public void downloadHype(object data)
        {
            int index = (int)data;
            String tempUrl = String.Format("http://slyduck.com/hypemachine/frontend.php?intent=2&guid={0}", games[index].GuidString);

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(tempUrl));
            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(
                delegate(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Error == null)
                    {
                        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
                        games[index].Hype = (from item in xdoc.Descendants("hype")
                                     select new Hype()
                                     {
                                         Id = uint.Parse(item.Element("id").Value),
                                         GameId = uint.Parse(item.Element("game_id").Value),
                                         UserId = uint.Parse(item.Element("user_id").Value),
                                         Score = (uint.Parse(item.Element("score").Value) == 1)
                                     }).ToList();
                    }
                });
}
```

Is there an easier way for me to organize this? I considered the possibility of sending an array of the game guids as a GET or POST parameter to alleviate some of the garbage generated by creating so many WebClients, but I'm unsure if that's the right solution.

I've looked into Synchronization classes and Parallel classes, however they aren't available  within SilverLight's .NET implementation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You spawn too many Threads. Remeber, a new Thread consumes 1MB of Virtual Address Space straight away.

If you have one user which has an ID (GUID), get the data by the guid (as you do know), but your XML should be as a list of Hype, not just a single one.

In other words, use a diffrent strutcture of XML. Then you just need one backgroud thread and one WebClient to fetch the whole list.

Comment: Well, the script used above simply grabs all of the hype scores for any particular game, selected by the games guid. When the app starts, I need to download the hype scores, as well as comments (done in a similar fashion) for each game that is going to be displayed (typically 15 at any given moment). I could issue one request to grab ALL hypes for ALL games, then sort them out in C#, however I'm expecting the games to be cycled on a very frequent basis, so fetching ALL hypes for ALL games would eventually cause downloads to become massive.